# Which do you do first, roll for character stats or give your character a back story?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I don't play any tabletop RPGs right now, but it is something I am rather interested in doing, and as such I've devised a character backstory that I would be able to use in fantasy-style tabletop games.

However, I'm worried that, should I ever get into a tabletop scenario, that said backstory might be useless if the dice don't roll in my favour when it comes time to actually make my character.

As such, I felt it a wise idea to ask here as to whether you guys create a characters' backstory before you roll for stats, and then give reasons for said stats that align with the backstory, or do you roll for stats first and then create a backstory based around those stats?

For clarity sake, let's just assume I'm talking about D&D and Pathfinder; and whether either of those systems have recommendations on which order to go with for constructing a character.

(Or if there is a tried and tested way of which one works best)

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a traditional discussion forum, and we try to give answers tailored to the user's specific situation. In this case, that means we'd need to know what game (system/edition) you're planning to try, as different systems may produce very different answers to your question. Please [edit] your question to include a system/edition tag. And if you want to discuss RPG things in a less structured format, the [chat] is always open once you've got 20+ rep!

Comment: Is this actually "unclear?"  I feel like I understand *exactly* what is being asked here.  I could be convinced of other issues, like "too broad" or such.

Comment: @SouthpawHare  Since we need additional detail -- an actual system to cover this on -- "unclear what you're asking" is reasonable. ("Add additional details" is in that close reason's description.) The answer to this question varies on the system. Some systems have an actual order for this, or orders that make sense, and they aren't the same as in other systems. In some systems it can go any which way. Many systems I've played don't even have a concept of rolling for stats.

Comment: Yeah, various games do it differently, and outside the scope of a game it's really just asking what people personally prefer.   It's not really all that interesting whether this is closed for too broad, unclear, or opinion based - that's the core issue.

Comment: "Fantasy style RPGs" is a very broad set of games that don't have mechanics in common here -- just D&D and its derivatives like Pathfinder do, specifically because they're all rooted in how D&D does things. Fantasy games includes games such as Masters of Umdaar and Dungeon World which have little in common with those two mechanically. However, scoping to D&D and Pathfinder specifically is probably enough for reopening this.

Comment: @doppelgreener As mxy pointed out, system aside, this is still a survey question.

Comment: @Miniman Within the scope of the games given I think we can at least advise on, say, the lack of a correct way to do it, or the variations in how people handle it.

Comment: Given one system, this question should be answerable with the usual rules citation. Sticking with D&D as a games family could be viable if reworked into "how has X changed over time in D&D". Until either of those happens, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

### This order isn't specified in the rules, so do as you want

You can choose any order that is convenient for you, since the rules don't say much about backstories at all (unless we're talking mechanical things like 5e backgrounds). You can roll for the stats first, and then write the backstory, or vice versa, as you like (that might depend on the method of determining ability scores, see below). The DM might require a specific order though,  so collaborate with the DM.

Usually you get a character idea first, roll for the scores second, and then assign the results as you see fit the idea:

> "I am a strong tough thug, so I assign my highest rolls to STR and CON"

The case when you probably want to roll first is the one when you don't distribute the results, but use random distribution instead (first roll for STR, second for DEX, etc.):

> "My highest ability scores are STR and CON - it seems my character is strong and tough, so I make him a thug"